# Issue passing function to child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i'm expecting this to be something very simple that I am too tired and overlooked, but hoping someone can help!

I have a function that my parent component inherits from the provider. I am attempting to pass the function to the child with the below:

```
console.log(typeof(runServerless))
<VaultEntry contactInfo={userData} runServerless={runServerless}/>
```

That console log shows a array and if I directly log the function, it shows the function. Now, immediately upon VaultEntry:

```
export const VaultEntry = (contactInfo, runServerless) => {
      console.log(runServerless)
}
```

that console.log returns a blank object and I can't call it.

Soooo hoping someone knows what thing I am missing. Appreciate all the help! Thank yoU!

Comment: React functional components take a single properties object, I imagine your `contactInfo` prop contains a `runServerless` property (You could destructure that object so both props are available using `({contactInfo, runServerless}) => {...}` )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

function components take props as first argument

```js
export const VaultEntry = (props) => {
      console.log(props.runServerless)
}
```

If you want the props values directly without `props.runServerless` you need to deconstruct the props argument on declaration inline

```js
export const VaultEntry = ({ contactInfo, runServerless }) => {
      console.log(props.runServerless)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to descructure it like:

```
export const VaultEntry = ({contactInfo, runServerless}) => {
      console.log(runServerless)
}
```

so add `{}` in props and it should work fine